# Add CAB file to the OS design

Tags: windows-ce, platform-builder

I need to add the CAB file (my installation) to the OS Design and I can't find a way to do that. 
I need it for Installing the program automatically when the OS loads for the first time.
I'm talking about win compact 7.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused.  Why would you add the CAB to the OS design and have that unpack on run?  If you're creating an OS and you want it to include the app, why not just use the BIB and REG files (PLATFORM or PROJECT) to just put your app's files and registry entries into the OS where you want them in the first place?

**EDIT**

If you must use a CAB file (and I'd still be highly recommend creating a BIB file for this work instead), then just include a shortcut in your device's `\Windows\Startup` folder (a BIB and DAT file pair can do that) that runs you cab file.  The contents of the shortcut would look something like this:

**EDIT2**

BIB Files are the way Windows CE determines what files go into the OS (REG files similarly define registry entries).  In a broad, handwaving explanation, all BIB files from the system and your OS design get coalesced into a file called ce.bib during `makeimg` and that file is parsed to generate the `nk.bin`.

Some worthwhile reading:

- [Inside the Build System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa459173.aspx) (old, but still valid)
- [[Binary Image Builder files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee478797.aspx)
- [Using BIB files](http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2008/06/17/platform-builder-using-bib-files-to-add-files-to-a.aspx)
- [Adding apps to the Start Menu](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehall/archive/2007/07/26/adding-applications-to-the-windows-ce-start-menu.aspx) (covers shortcuts, etc)

> 41#\windows\wceload.exe \windows\mycab.cab

Comment: because it will be a lot easier for me. I'm creating the CAB file every release for updates, so for me, in order to change the release image I will only need to change the CAB file.

Comment: If I would like to create a BIB file for this work, where should I start? (I never worked with bib files before)

Comment: I had to remove the project that contained the CAB file and when i added him again the final image does not contain the CAB. i checked the ce.bib and i don't see there the cab file, its line he don't include the myProject.bib file. I have the file in the release folder.  do you have any idea what i have done wrong?

Comment: Having the file in the release folder isn't enough.  You must add an entry for it to one of the BIB files manually.  The source location can be anywhere (doesn't have to be in the release directory)

Comment: I have added the file to the project bib file. I have tried sysgen, build current bsp and subprojects, make run time image and I still have no effect. Maybe I need to build something else?

Comment: *Which* project.bib file did you qadd it to?  You have to add it to the original (in FILES), then copy that one to the FLATRELEASEDIR and makeimg again.  makeimg doesn't copy the FILES over automatically, and if you're modifying the BIB in the  release directory, it gets overwritten on  SYSGEN when the copy does happen.  Bottom line, check ce.bib to see if it's getting copied.  If not, you've made a mistake - likely in which file you modified or a failure to copy to the release directory.